# Tenembaum's book on prime numbers

Tags: number-theory, reference-request

In Tenembaum's book "The Prime Numbers and Their Distribution", Ch. 3.2, last paragraph of page 53, it is stated that (Z/qZ)* is a cyclic group.
I feel like I am missing something here since for example q=8 disproves the statement.
Can anyone help here with what the author means?

Thanks!
Marco

Comment: $q$ should be a prime, probably. Or see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n for a more general statement.

Answer (score 2):

Check the previous paragraph, Tenenbaum says "Let us first consider, for simplicity, the case of a progression $a$ (mod $q$) with $q$ **prime** and $1 \leq a < q$."  (Emphasis mine.)

Comment: Oooops, sorry, I can't believe I did not see it, I checked at least three times :-o
Thank you!